# Barchart or Histogram for number of data rows and columns cells, in Javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, histogram, bar-chart

I am new with the language, but currently have a task to finish. I need to construct a bar chart or histogram from the csv. Now, in this case, these charts should not be based on the frequency of some values, it should be based on number of filled data cells in the csv file.

For example for values like

[image]

it should construct a vertically upset down histogram wherein, X axis are C1,C2 and y axis with the length of 4. So C1 bar with length 4. Thus it will create a uniform histogram..

So, far I am using PapaParse to extract the CSV values to array object. but could not able form the above logic on that array object. I did try the splitfunction for data extraction but found papaparse, an easier way.  Also tried d3, but it has issue with the large proportion of data thus will not be using this. Moreover these histogram will only be for analysis and not for final output. Thus I am not much concerned with the its graphical aspects. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this library [d3.js](http://d3js.org/) as base.

And ready to go solutions lib dependent on d3.js - [nvd3.js](http://nvd3.org/).

You can find anything you want.

Here [examples](http://nvd3.org/examples/index.html)

There are a lot of other libs, it's my most preferable.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I did check those example, there is no such example that counts the number of rows from each column and display the bar length accordingly..